# Add database to existing MySQL master-master replication which uses binlog_do_db?

Tags: mysql, replication, master-master-replication

We have 2 `Mysql 5.7` servers running in master-master replication mode.

And there is a database replicating between these 2 servers:

```
binlog_do_db = database1
```

Now we need to add a new database into replication, I have read [Add database to existing replication which uses binlog_do_db?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76194/add-database-to-existing-replication-which-uses-binlog-do-db), but its for master-slave. Is there any other things should be considered for master-master situation?

Comment: What is the method your are using ? Galera Cluster or Group Replication ? or older method ?

Answer (score 0):

Master-Master is simply Master-Slave in both directions.  So all the settings work the same.

Data does not endlessly loop between the two Masters as long as they don't have the same `server_id`.

I'm pretty sure you simply have multiple lines.  See https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?26,255998,255998

M-M is fraught with perils, but I guess you have gotten past them.  So I won't harp on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can Edit my.cnf to include many new databases as you want but binlog-do-db behaves itself if you have always selected your database before run your query.

**By example** you have 3 datatabases on your master 1 and would like to replicate only 2 on master 2 and use this solution :

*binlog_do_db = database1*

binlog_do_db = database2

by running this query on master1 :

delete from database3.testTable where id='yy';

will broke your replication because database3 does not exists on master2: please read this article from percona before filtering 
https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/05/14/why-mysqls-binlog-do-db-option-is-dangerous/